# Angular - Trying to use @HostListener for drop event

Tags: javascript, angular, drop

I'm trying to create a directive to drag & drop files.

I managed to handle the dragenter and the dragleave, but the drop event is completely being ignored.

```js
@HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
onDrop(event: Event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('drop!');
}

@HostListener('dragenter', ['$event'])
onDragOver(event: DragEvent): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log("drag enter");
}

@HostListener('dragleave', ['$event'])
onDragLeave(event: DragEvent): void {
  console.log("drag leave");
}
```

I have also tried `@HostListener('(body/window):drop', etc..)` and dropped a file anywhere in the window, but the console log is never triggered.

I have also tried to add `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` to all the hostlistener.

`dragenter` and `dragleave` are properly fired when entering/exiting the drop area.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there's an issue with the `@HostListener` for the 'drop' event. The 'drop' event is not directly available on the host element because it is a global event, and you won't be able to capture it using `@HostListener`, you need to add the event listener to the window or document object directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

To enable the listening of drop event, I first need to preventDefault on `dragover` events.

```js
@HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```